# Python Eventlet spawn not executing concurrently

Tags: python, eventlet

I have following two versions of code using eventlet. The expectation is that the 2 spawn_n calls will execute concurrently, but thats not the case. The execution happens serially.

```
import eventlet
import threading
import datetime
from eventlet.green import urllib2


def hello(name):
    print eventlet.greenthread.getcurrent(), threading.current_thread()
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    print " %s hello !!" % name
    urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif").read()

eventlet.spawn(hello, 'abc')
eventlet.spawn(hello, 'xyz')
eventlet.sleep(0)
```

O/P:    <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140365670881088)>
2016-08-09 14:04:57.782866
 abc hello !!
 <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140365670881088)>
2016-08-09 14:05:02.929903
 xyz hello !!

```
import eventlet
import threading
import datetime
from eventlet.green import urllib2


def hello(name):
    print eventlet.greenthread.getcurrent(), threading.current_thread()
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    print " %s hello !!" % name
    urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif").read()

pool = eventlet.GreenPool(size=4)
pool.spawn_n(hello, 'pqr')
pool.spawn_n(hello, 'lmn')
pool.waitall()
```

O/P:    <_MainThread(MainThread, started 139897149990720)>
2016-08-09 14:05:25.613546
 pqr hello !!
 <_MainThread(MainThread, started 139897149990720)>
2016-08-09 14:05:30.699473
 lmn hello !!

In both the versions of the code, the call happens sequentially.

Comment: After I added another eventlet.spawn_n(hello, 'def') or poll.spawn_n(hello, 'rst'). The last 2 calls happens  with difference of few milliseconds. As of documentation, the eventlets is not pure concurrent. Is there anyway to execute in real concurrent way with very less modifications?

Comment: Define `concurrently` and how is it different from `sequentially`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(tag):
  print('{0} begin'.format(tag))
  eventlet.sleep(0.1)  # pretty much the same as running HTTP request and throwing results away
  print('{0} end'.format(tag))

t1 = time.time()
pool.spawn(fun, 'Turtle')
pool.spawn(fun, 'Achilles')
pool.waitall()
tt = time.time() - t1
print('Total time: {0:.2f}'.format(tt))
```

And you would see output similar to this:

```
Turtle begin
Achilles begin
Turtle end
Achilles end
Total time: 0.10
```

Which shows that execution of functions was interleaved at IO waiting points (sleep), which is close to definition of cooperative concurrency. Also notice that total time is not sum of two sleeps, but maximum + infrastructure overhead (should be close to nothing in this synthetic test).

Code in question could not show this because you only had prints (which don't create IO wait in Eventlet) before IO and none after. So what you actually had executing is this:

```
main: pool.waitall() begin, switch to Eventlet loop
loop: oh, there are greenthreads scheduled to run now, switch to 1
1: print this
1: print that
1: urllib... start network IO, switch to loop
loop: there is another green thread scheduled, switch to 2
2: print this
2: print that
2: urllib... start network IO, switch to Eventlet loop
loop: wait for any event that should wake greenthread,
  suppose that would be thread 1 urllib that is finished first
1: HTTP request finished, thread 1 finished, but no code to prove it
loop: wait for any event...
2: HTTP request finished, thread 2 finished
main: pool.waitall() finished
```